# Append two columns from text file into single list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a space delimited text file (temp.txt) as follows:

```
a susan python
b rick java
c bella scala
```

I want to read this into a set, as follows:

```
{'susan python', 'rick java', 'bella scala'}
```

I've tried the following code, but it only returns `{'bella scala'}`

```
temp_List = [];

with open('temp.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        splitLine = line.split();
        master_set = [" ".join(splitLine[1:])];

temp_Set = set(temp_List);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you can simply use array **append** function and remove *temp_Set = set(temp_List)*

```
temp_List = []
with open('temp.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        splitLine = line.split()
        master_set = [" ".join(splitLine[1:])]
        temp_List.append(master_set[0])
print temp_List
```

Here we simply append elements and we get output:

```
['susan python', 'rick java', 'bella scala']
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those cases where the function [String.partition](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) works really well.

```
temp_set = set()
with open('temp.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        _, _, name = line.partition(' ')
        temp_set.add(name)
```

it is also possible to replace

```
_, _, name = line.partition(' ')
```

with

```
_, name = line.split(' ', 1) # where the 1 specifies the maximum number of splits
```

#### Why your code did not work:

1. nothing is appended to `temp_List`, so `temp_Set` is also empty
2. `master_set` is overwritten in every iteration, and in the last iteration is assigned `['bella scala']` through this assignment `= [" ".join(splitLine[1:])]`

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not work because you are not appending results to `temp_List`.

For this problem, you can use `csv` module with a dictionary comprehension. `csv.reader` returns an iterator which then feeds the comprehension.

```
from io import StringIO
import csv

mystr = StringIO("""a susan python
b rick java
c bella scala""")

# replace mystr with open('temp.txt', 'r')
with mystr as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ')
    res = {' '.join(i[1:]) for i in reader}

print(res)

{'susan python', 'rick java', 'bella scala'}
```

Answer (score 0):

**@TanviP**, you can try the below code.

> **Note:** `set()` does not preserve the order of elements like `lists`. So, it's better to use list if the order matters otherwise you will need to go for 3rd party libraries to use OrderedDict() etc.
>
> I have used  **list** and **set** both to show you the difference. Add more data lines to **temp.txt** and run code to see the differences in the order of items (sometimes you'll find **set**'s elements in different order than that of the corresponding **list**).

```
temp_ordered_list = []

with open("temp.txt") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        data_list = line.strip().split()
        temp_ordered_list.append(" ".join(data_list[1:]))

temp_unordered_set = set(temp_ordered_list)
print(temp_ordered_list);  # ['susan python', 'rick java', 'bella scala'}
print(temp_unordered_set);  # {'susan python', 'rick java', 'bella scala'}
```

Thanks.